# Getting an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when using Yup.string.test() for a validation. Using Formik and Yup

Tags: formik, yup

I'm trying to implement a third party validation inside a `useFormik` && `Yup` validation, but I'm getting a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isValidIBAN')`the moment I'm trying to start typing something on the input. It  breaks on the `Yup.test()` function,  I don't know what I 'm doing wrong.

This is my existing code.

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'

import ibantools, { electronicFormatIBAN } from 'ibantools'

function BankDetails({}: BankDetailsProps) {


// ommitted code 

const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      bankAccountNumber: '',
      bicNumber: '',
      policyNumber: '',
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      bankAccountNumber: Yup.string()
        .transform(function (value) {
          if (!this.isType(value)) return value
          return electronicFormatIBAN(value). // Converts the user input into a valid IBAN
        })
        .test({
          name: 'is-valid-iban',
          message: t('Forms.BankDetails.Errors.InvalidIBAN'),
          exclusive: true,
          // @ts-ignore
          test: (value) => ibantools.isValidIBAN(value),  // TESTS that user input is a valid IBAN  [ERROR]: Typerror here. Uncaught in Promise. Cannot read promerty of undefined reading 
          // console.log(value, 'inside iban')
        })


      })
    })
  }


  return {
          <form className="flex flex-col pt-4">
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="bankAccountNumber" className="mt-2">
            {t('Forms.BankDetails.IBANLabel')}
          </Label>
          <Input
            kind="text"
            error={formik.errors.bankAccountNumber}
            name="bankAccountNumber"
            value={formik.values.bankAccountNumber}
            touched={formik.touched.bankAccountNumber}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          />
        </div>
    </form>
  }
```

What I would like is to

1. get user input
2. convert it into a valid iban using `electronicFormatIBAN(value)`
3. test that it is a valid iban with `isValidIBAN()` inside the Yup.test()
4. return that string

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue by removing the `ibantools` from this call

```
      .test({
          name: 'is-valid-iban',
          message: t('Forms.BankDetails.Errors.InvalidIBAN'),
          exclusive: true,
          // @ts-ignore
          test: (value) => ibantools.isValidIBAN(value), // [NOTE] remove ibantools from here
          // console.log(value, 'inside iban')
        })
```

Now just doing it liek this and it works

```
        .test({
          name: 'is-valid-iban',
          message: t('Forms.BankDetails.Errors.InvalidIBAN'),
          exclusive: true,
          // @ts-ignore
          test: (value) => isValidIBAN(value),
        })
```

However how come `ibantools` is not available inside that `.test()` context but `isValidIBAN` is ??